# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver, digital-ocean

I am trying to automate data scraping through Digital Ocean droplet. However, I get an error when I try to run this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

PATH = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)

sleep(2)
link = "https://freightpower.schneider.com/shipper"
driver.get(link)
```

I get the error in the last line - driver.get(link)

Do you have any suggestion what it could be the reason and to fix it?

[image]

Comment: I would resolve the urllib3 version error first. Could easily be why the web driver is failing. pip3 install requests